How to generate charts using highcharts-export-server in a dotnet project hosted in Azure?
I have a project runing in dotnet8.0 which was runing (in local) a highchart server using the npm package highcharts-export-server version 2.0.24. It was initially based on node version 12.14.
This project is deployed in an Azure web application using the dotnet 8.0 stack.
In this project I had one API that was just doing a call to this highcharts-export-server and then was returning the chart.
Hosted service in charge of launching the highcharts-export-server:
 public class ExportServerService
     : IHostedService
 {
     private readonly ProcessStartInfo _startInfo;
     private readonly Process _process;
     private readonly ILogger<ExportServerService> _logger;
     private readonly string NodeJsExecPath;

     public ExportServerService(
         ILogger<ExportServerService> logger,
         IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime,
         IOptions<NodeJSOptions> options)
     {
         _logger = logger;
         applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(this.KillNodeProcess);

         var nodeJsSettings = options.Value;
         NodeJsExecPath = nodeJsSettings.ExecPath.Replace("/node.exe",string.Empty);
         _startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(nodeJsSettings.ExecPath);
         _startInfo.Arguments = $"{nodeJsSettings.HighchartsPath} --enableServer 1 --host {nodeJsSettings.HostName} --port {nodeJsSettings.Port}";
         _startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
         _startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
         _startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

         _process = new Process();

         _process.StartInfo = _startInfo;
     }

     private void KillNodeProcess()
     {
         if (_process != null)
         {
             if (!_process.HasExited)
             {
                 _process.Kill();
                 _process.WaitForExit();
             }

             _process.Exited -= _process_Exited;
         }
     }

     public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation($"Lancement du server highcharts");
         _process.Start();
         _process.Exited += _process_Exited;
         _logger.LogInformation($"Start Async => server highchart lancé");

         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }


     private void _process_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("process exited");
     }

     public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation($"Stop Async");
         return Task.CompletedTask;
     }
}


API to generate the chart :
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Post(
     [FromBody] HighChartOptions value,
     [FromServices] IOptions<NodeJSOptions> options)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation($"Request to generate chart : {JsonSerializer.Serialize(value)}");
     var correlationId = Ulid.NewUlid();
     var httpClient = new HttpClient();

     // call to the highcharts-export-server running on localhost:7801
     var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(
         $"http://{options.Value.HostName}:{options.Value.Port}/",
         new StringContent(
             JsonSerializer.Serialize(value),
             Encoding.UTF8,
             MediaTypeNames.Application.Json
         )
     );

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation($"Create OK of{correlationId}.jpeg");
         var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
         return File(result, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg, $"{correlationId}.jpeg");
     }
     else
     {
         _logger.LogError($"Highcharts error : {response.StatusCode.ToString()}. Content : {await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
         return BadRequest();
     }
 }

But since the summer change time, all my charts are showing all the data 1 hour before the real hour. (but all chart generated on a period before the summer change time are on the good hour).
Highchart version 3.0.1 fixed the issue so I tried to update the version and since that my server isn't running correctly anymore.
First of all highcharts-export-server need a node version higher than 16.16.0 therefore I updated my node version to 20.14.0 to have the last up to date.
I updated my highcharts-export-server package to version 3.0.1 and then tried to publish.
When I published I had a problem due to puppeteer (new dependency added by highcharts-export-server v3.0.1) I had the following error :
(https://i.sstatic.net/6KgevFBM.png)
So I ran the npx puppeteer browsers install chrome command just before starting the server, and ran it in the folder containing my node.exe.
And I had the following error :
1
So I decided to create an API allowing me to execute some command in order to install chrome this way and it worked ! I could install chrome but I had still the same error as the first time : puppeteer wasn't able to find the chrome version installed. I tried to find it myself by navigating through the folder and I couldn't find my chrome version neither (even by reaching the path I got by running the npx puppeteer browsers install chrome command).
So I tried to change the puppeteer cache folder in order to have it at the root of my project and be sure that I could find chrome.
So in my application environments variable I added the PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR to C:/home/site/wwwroot
and added chrome from my computer (installed by running the puppeteer command) via ftp.
Once again, chrome is correctly installed in the folder C:/home/site/wwwroot/chrome but now in my highcharts-export-server log I have the following error :
(https://i.sstatic.net/cwj0719g.png)
So I tried by running the command directly in my project using my API and got the exact same result.
So I tried to add another environment variable of puppeteer : PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH and set up my path the the chrome executable : C:/home/site/wwwroot/chrome/win64-125.0.6422.141/chrome-win64/chrome.exe
And now I jave the following error :
(https://i.sstatic.net/gwtQET7I.png)
Then the server starts correctly but can't find any worker so I can't generate any charts.
How can I make it work on my azure web application (I need my API to return me the bytes of the chart generated)?

UPDATE :
I finally drop the idea to make my server work on a dotnet project. I make it run in a docker container and deploy it on an Azure Container App in which I can use the Api I needed.
Here is the DockerFile I use if anyone need it :
FROM node:lts-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV HIGHCHARTS_VERSION=11.4.0
ENV SERVER_ENABLE=true
ENV SERVER_SSL_ENABLE=true

RUN apk add --no-cache \
      chromium \
      nss \
      freetype \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont \
      nodejs \
      yarn

ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser
RUN npm install highcharts-export-server -g
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7801
ENTRYPOINT ["highcharts-export-server", "--enableServer", "1", "--port", "7801"]


If Possible, Share your code or github repository?

I don't have a github repository for this project, what part would you like ?

can you share the code that has the main logic ?

I followed this blog and able to generate charts, please check this once.

Hi, what version of Highcharts .NET Wrapper do you use?

@Thomas Fabre, if you're deploying your app to Azure App Service (Linux), try adding npx puppeteer browsers install chrome to the startup command in the configuration section of the Azure App.

Hi, continuing duplicated forum topic there, you can export your chart to .jpg using exportChart() method. Example demo. When it comes to the time shift, setting time.useUTC to false should fix the issue

Hi @magdalena, I am not using any. I generate my charts by requesting the highcharts-export-server that is launched by my ExportServerService. Then I read the chart as byte and return it as a jpeg image in my POST api. So I am not using any currently

@Sirra Sneha, Hi. my azure web app is deployed on windows so I don't find any start up command field in the configuration of my app, but won't I have the same result as when I try to run it just before starting my server ?

@ThomasFabre unfortunately there's no specific guide for Azure yet. How about using Docker like here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/451
Does that work for you?

@Jakub Szuminski I haven't think about going through a docker and it work like a charm  ! Thank you !
